# office outlook rule : copy all messages except from a specific user

Tags: ms-office, outlook-2013

I am using Microsoft Office Outlook 2013 and I want to setup a rule to copy all messages which appears in inbox in a separate folder except a specific set of messages which are coming from a specific user. I am able to setup the rule but the except part I am unable to configure i.e. `copy all messages except from this specific user`.

Please suggest how I can configure that. Is this can be done by introducing any VB script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the Rules and Alerts window (Home > Rules > Manage Rules & Alerts...)and click "New Rule...", the Rules Wizard will pop up.  Ignore the first page, set up your conditions and triggers on the next two pages.  The fourth page will have "Except if from people or publix group" at the top.  Check the box, and click the underlined text at the bottom to enter the details of the excepted account.

You can also get to the wizard by clicking the "Advanced Options..." button in the Create Rule window (Home > Rules > Create Rule).